# why text alignment of formula field and labels changed in print?

Tags: crystal-reports

I use visual studio 2013 and crystal report 13-0-10.
alignment of formula field and labels are correct in preview mode, but when I print crystal report file alignment of them change from center to lefttoright.

How can I have them center alignment?

Best Regards

Comment: Have you found the solution ؟

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the settings of the report as the paper you would like to print on, e.g. A4 Size paper>> open the report >> select crystal report menu>> Design >> Page setup>> in the printer option area check the option (No Printer optimize for screen display) then from page option select (A4 (210x297mm)) and try.

Or you can check you text object alignment left center or right and your paragraph radio buttons left-to-right or right-to-left.